# Skewed Div - Right Side Only

Tags: html, css, rotation, pseudo-element, skew

I'm trying to create a div like the one below:

[image: Skewed Text Area]

What's the best way of going about it. I'm sorry for the lack of code but I think everything I have tried is on the wrong lines. I've tried rotating a div but the entire left side needs to stay at straight angles.

Is this possible?

Comment: Save this image and use it as a background image ;)

Comment: But if i do that I will need to resize the image every time it's used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.normal {
    background: gray;
      height: 200px;
    width: 50%;
    position: relative;
    padding: 20px;
}

.slanted {
    background: skyblue;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius:20px;
    height: 200px;
    width: 90%;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 20px;
      transform: skewY(4deg);

}
```

```html
<div class="normal">
<div class="slanted">
    <h2>Hello World!</h2>
    <p>This was you are trying to get i Hope</p>
</div>
  <div>
```

Comment: The only problem with the answer is above is that it doesn't skew the right side of the div as well. :/